# How to enable session tracking in android application client

Tags: android, web-services, session, soap

I'm now developing my first Android application.

My application interacts with a web service using SOAP messages.
The web service sits in `glassfish4` server.

So I want that every user that interacts with the web service will get a new instance of the class that represents the web service.

I read how to do this, I need to add the `@HttpSessionScope` annotation to the web service class.

But what should I write on the client side, in the android application to enable the session tracking?

Thanks

Comment: The code is very big, and there is no need for the code, it's a general question. I just want to know how to enable the session tracking from the client side when the client is android app.

Comment: maybe there is another solution except for @HttpSessionScope annotation. I can use another solution also.

Comment: no one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There shoud be a webservice for the android user login. 
The result of the webservice should also contain the session id of the logged in user (only if the user is logged in). 
And the session can be tracked by passing the session id as a cookie in the request header (or request property).
Here is a java code referred from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329846/accessing-file-over-a-network-using-service-account-in-java/21330339#21330339) for making a request with request properties.

```
try {
            URL url  = new URL("https://visruthcv.appspot.com/project/listUsers");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) con;
            httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            /*
             * for request headers
             */
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset",
                    "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=9550495DDC72AAC410B07B6C16908CB5");


            /*
             * for adding request parameters
             */
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("username", "Visruth");
            params.put("password", "passwd");

            OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            httpUrlConnection.connect();

            // To write to a file, something like this
            InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/visruth/Desktop/output.txt");
            int i = 0;
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];

            while((i = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

In the above code, `httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=9550495DDC72AAC410B07B6C16908CB5");` sets the session id (`9550495DDC72AAC410B07B6C16908CB5`) as a cookie in the request propery. The cookie value format is `JSESSIONID=9550495DDC72AAC410B07B6C16908CB5`, in which `9550495DDC72AAC410B07B6C16908CB5` is only what the session id created in the web. Make each request by adding the cookie may track the session.